# How to change image in listview based on condition

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms

I need to change the image in listview based on boolean condition

In My App.cs class i will declare boolean property

`public static bool isLightThemeApplied = true`

In MainPage.xaml

i am using Master Detail Page. In Master View, I am displaying listView as

```
<ListView x:Name="lstMenu" Margin="0" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="0" ItemSelected="Items_ItemSelected"
                    SelectionMode="Single" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" RowHeight="45"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never" BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PageBackgroundColor}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid Margin="10,1">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Image Source="{Binding IconSource}" HeightRequest="45" WidthRequest="60"  HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="0,0,5,0">
                                    <Image.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="Image">
                                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Image.Style>
                                </Image>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Title}" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" MaxLines="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="{DynamicResource PrimaryTextColor}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>               
            </ListView>
```

MainPage.cs

```
BindingContext = new ViewModel();
```

```
public class SubItems
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string IconSource { get; set; }
    }
```

ViewModel.cs

```
public ViewModel()
{

            Items.Add(new SubItems() { Title = "Menu", IconSource = App.IsLightTheme ? "menu.png" : "down.png" });
            Items.Add(new SubItems() { Title = "Stage1", IconSource = "ic_action.png" });
            PD100Items.Add(new SubItems() { Title = "Stage2", IconSource = "ground.png" });
            Items.Add(new SubItems() { Title = "Stage3", IconSource = "ic_helo.png" });
                       Items.Add(new SubItems() { Title = "LOGOUT", IconSource = "ic_logout.png" });

        }
```

In DetailPage , i will use ActionSheet to change themes

```
private async void OnItemClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var actionSheet = await DisplayActionSheet("Theme", "Cancel", null, "Light", "Dark");

            if (mergedDictionaries != null)
            {
                mergedDictionaries.Clear();
                switch (actionSheet)
                {
                    case "Light":
                        mergedDictionaries.Add(new LightTheme());
                        App.IsLightTheme = true;
                        break;

                    case "Dark":
                        mergedDictionaries.Add(new DarkTheme());
                        App.IsLightTheme = false;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

My Problem is on theme changed from light theme to dark theme, when drawer opens the image should be changed. how to acheive this scenario?

Any help is really appreciated

Comment: Why not just: `Items.Where(s => s.Title == 'Menu').IconSource = App.IsLightTheme ? "menu.png" : "down.png"` ? Just wrap this code around a method, and call it inside your switch cases.. If the binded collection changes, the `Listview` should refresh

Comment: i have two pages in master. If i change the page your comment will not work

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `INotifyPropertyChanged` to achieve this. If the value is updated, the UI will refresh automatically.

class SubItems

```
 public  class SubItems: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {    
        public void changeTheme(bool islight) {
          if ("Menu".Equals(Title)) { // if the function is only for only `Menu` Item
             if (islight)
             {// set to light theme
                if ( !App.isLightThemeApplied)
                {  
                    IconSource = "menu.png";
                }
             }
             else
             {//set to unlight theme
                if (App.isLightThemeApplied) {
                    IconSource = "down.png";
                }
             }
          }
        }    

        string _title;
        public string Title
        {
            set { SetProperty(ref _title, value); }

            get { return _title; }
        }

        string _iconSource;
        public string IconSource
        {
            set { SetProperty(ref _iconSource, value); }

            get { return _iconSource; }
        }    

        bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
                return false;

            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

When you change the value of `App.IsLightTheme`, you could call function `changeTheme` to change the value of `IconSource`.

```
                case "Light":
                    mergedDictionaries.Add(new LightTheme());
                    App.IsLightTheme = true;

                    //change theme here
                     viewmodel.changeTheme(true);
                    break;

                case "Dark":
                    mergedDictionaries.Add(new DarkTheme());
                    App.IsLightTheme = false;

                    //change theme here
                     viewmodel.changeTheme(false);
                    break;
```

Note:`viewmodel` is the instance of `ViewModel` you binding to `MainPage`.